# Missing CommandBars.Item

Tags: c#, visual-studio-addins, commandbar

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars;

In the following sample.

```
var applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
var allCommands = ((CommandBars)applicationObject.CommandBars);
```

Simple question: Why am I missing `allComands.Item[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the indexer directly:

```
allCommands["..."]
```